# How can I save fetched JSON to a custom object's custom field. JSON parameters do not have same name as custom fields

Tags: apex, json, javascript-controller

On doing Something like this:

```
o.FieldName__c = str[i].FieldName; 

//o instance of Custom Object and str is deserialized List.
```

An error pops up showing 'variable does not exist: FieldName'. If I use JSON parameter same as API name of custom field problem resolves.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify what type you deserialize into, and what your alternative approach looks like (rather than just describing it).

Answer (score 2):

The deserialized object is most likely a Map, so you'd do something like:

```
o.FieldName__c = (String)((Map<String,Object>)str[i]).get('FieldName');
```

Or, expanded:

```
Map<String, Object> row = (Map<String, Object>)str[i];
o.FieldName__c = (String)row.get('FieldName');
```

In either case, we are using [casting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) to convert from a basic object to a concrete subtype that we can use to access individual properties of the object.